# Cache css/js from PHP processor

Tags: php, caching

I've built a php processor to process all my css and js files.

The .htaccess rewrites the css and js files to point to the processor.

The processor gets the contents of the css/js file, processes it and then outputs to the browser.

For some reason the css and js files refuse to cache?
I've set the "Expires" and "Cache-Control" headers, but still no luck.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

*edit*

Here's some of the code:

```
function setExpires($expires) {  
 header('Expires: '.gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s', time()+$expires).' GMT');  
 header("Cache-Control: max-age=$expires, public");
 header("Connection: close");
}
```

I'm using Google Chrome dev tools. The headers coming back are this:

```
Request URL:http://www.static.do-u-know.net/css/common.1286502074.css
Request Method:GET
Status Code:200 OK

Request Headers
Accept:text/css,*/*;q=0.1
Cache-Control:max-age=0
Referer:http://www.do-u-know.net/frame.php
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US) AppleWebKit/534.3 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/6.0.472.63 Safari/534.3

Response Headers
Cache-Control:max-age=631138519, public
Connection:close
Content-Encoding:gzip
Content-Type:text/css
Date:Fri, 08 Oct 2010 02:41:12 GMT
Expires:Mon, 07 Oct 2030 22:56:31 GMT
Server:Apache/2.2.11 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.11 OpenSSL/0.9.8e-fips-rhel5 mod_auth_passthrough/2.1 mod_bwlimited/1.4 FrontPage/5.0.2.2635
Transfer-Encoding:chunked
Vary:Accept-Encoding
X-Powered-By:PHP/5.2.5
```

Comment: Show some code on how you are setting the headers; make sure they are received by the client, e.g. by using Firebug.

Comment: You are missing a space in `Mon, 07 Oct 2030 22:56:31GMT` don't know, could be that that renders the date invalid as a whole

Comment: Nope, fixed the space but it didn't make any difference.